# Max() over (partition by order by desc/asc) does not return correct value - internal working

Tags: sql, databricks

For Ex - When I run this query to get max salary i get wrong output

```
SELECT name,
         dept,
         salary,
         MAX(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY salary asc ) AS min
    FROM zone_hr_dev.employees;
```

[image]

When I use below query it is right :

```
SELECT name,
         dept,
         salary,
         MAX(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY salary desc ) AS min
    FROM zone_hr_dev.employees;
```

[image]

How max works internally on window_functions when partition_by and order_by is used

The output should have max value of each department.

Comment: You should remove the ORDER BY altogether. The ORDER BY should only play a role if you have the specified windows such as ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW or something like that. If all you want is the default MAX salary within the department, you should remove that ORDER BY.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags here;  please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)